# Problem using SharePoint 2013 Search to filter by managed property

Tags: 2013, search, publishing-site

In my SharePoint application, I have a managed metadata site column called `Taxonomia` and a custom content type inherited from `Welcome Page` that uses this column. I also have a custom page layout for this content type and some pages created that have that column filled with some terms.

The Search Service Application is installed and I would like to to be able to search for pages filtering by the column `Taxonomia`. To do this, I went to the "Search Schema" page in the SharePoint Central Admin and created a managed property also called `Taxonomia` that maps the crawled property `ows_Taxonomia`. Below there are the options marked for this property:

[image: Configuration of the managed property]

After creating it, I did an index reset and a full crawl but still I'm not able to get results for this managed property in the SharePoint search.

I have some pages created that have the `Taxonomia` column filled with the tag `Teste`, but any query searching for `Teste` or `Taxonomia:Teste` in the SharePoint search page or the REST API (www.site.com/_api/search/query?queryText='Taxonomia:Teste') won't return any results.

Am I doing something wrong in this process or missing some step?

Comment: Can you please add your edit as an answer, and mark it as the correct one so the question will be in a resolved state?

Comment: Ok, I moved it. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the pages were actually being indexed by the search engine but they were missing a lot of managed properties such as `ListItemID`, `ContentType` and of course the property I created. I noticed it when I searched for the page title using the [SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool](http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) and it returned the page with these properties empty.

It suddenly started working some time after without I change any configuration, however, sometimes when I activate the crawling it starts to fail again as it loses the property values. The only explanation I can find for this is that something in the search service is failing due to the low-resource virtual machine this SharePoint installation is running. We have 6.5GB of RAM and when the search crawling is active the RAM is almost filled up and the whole machine turns extremely slow.

I noticed that sometimes when the RAM usage is high this error occurs more frequently, while the properties tend to be crawled correctly when it is lower, but I can't confirm that this is the cause of the problem since I didn't increased the RAM on the server yet to test it more accurately.

**Short update:** after increasing the server configurations (mostly RAM), this problem is not occurring anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [SharePoint 2013 search query tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) listed on codeplex yet? It provides the opportunity to query sharepoint by the REST API and display all the properties you want. Maybe the property is not filled correctly? Maybe the property has been named differently? It will display it for you.

However, we are having a similar problem, not being able to query documents by content type (some work, some do not) and we do not know why. Managed Properties are filled correctly though.

Comment: Yes, I used this tool. I edited the post to add more information I noticed in the last days testing it.